# access memSQL from c++ code using MySQL c++ connector

Tags: c++, mysql, singlestore

We are going to use memSQL with memory optimized config (rowstore).
From the c++ code we need to run insert operations in very high rate.
So we want to get maximum performance. 
Questions:
1. What is the best approach to access memSQL from C++ code.
2. Does memSQL support the MySQL c++ connector?
3. Is the non blocking API for insert data to table (async mode)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a C++ MySQL client to connect to MemSQL (for example maybe this one: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/). I haven't used it myself, but it probably works - try it out.

For performance / non-blocking inserts, you can use multiple client threads running inserts concurrently.